# busybox nc server cannot accept new connection once the old one dropped out

Tags: busybox, netcat

BusyBox v1.36.1 (2023-07-17 18:29:09 UTC) multi-call binary.

I run minimal nc server like:

```
nc -lkp 12345
```

I can connect to it once `nc localhost 12345`. After ctr-C, the next attempt will fail.

however if I run something with `-e` it will work:

```
nc -lkp 12345 -e /bin/cat
```

Can anyone explain the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Not all versions of netcat even support `-e`.

Without `-e` netcat copies its stdin to the first thing that connects to it.
When that connection closes, it exits.

With the `-e` option, each new connection gets the output from a new execution of the supplied command.  If multiple things connect at once with `cat`, things might not go so well as multiple cats would all be trying to get input from stdin to send.